# docker-compose fork/exec permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-m1

Last night I updated Docker desktop to the latest version 4.10.1 and today when I tried to run my containers, I get this error:

[image]

```
Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: fork/exec [docker-app-path]/bin/docker-compose-v1: permission denied
```

I'm on a Mac with M1.

I checked some issues, where people suggest adding the command `RUN chmod 777 /root` to my Dockerfile, but I've got 8 separate apps running, and it's a team-shared repo, so updating the Dockerfiles for this is not the most viable solution.

Comment: may be this is your [issue](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/privileged-helper/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm having the same issue in my Mac with M1. It seems like an issue with the latest version of Docker Desktop, which is **4.10.1 (82475)**.

Downgrade to **Docker Desktop 4.9.1**:
[https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-491](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-4100)

Or run your container from Terminal:

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thx! I started it from the terminal once. After that the App was working properly and the error was gone

Answer (score 3):

Had this issue again after upgrading to macOS Monterey 12.5 while having Docker 4.10, but the upgrade of [Docker to 4.11.1](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-4111) solved it completely.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is permission issue with your docker-compose file, not Dockerfile of application. don't do 777 to /root.
May be below command will resolve your issue.

`which docker-compose`
this will give you the path of docker-compose

`chmod +rwx /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` replace /usr/local/bin/docker-compose with your docker-compose path